# How to reuse stream function destination in Spring Stream Kafka Processing

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I choose Kafka Streams to process some data with Spring Stream Kafka binder. So I define some Function Beans in Spring Stream, like below code,

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>, KStream<String, UserEvent>> process() {
    return input -> input.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key.get("ID").toString(), generateFrom(value)))
                         .filter((k, v) -> v != null);
}
```

For the configuration

```
spring:
cloud:
    stream:
        function:
            definition: userEventProcess;accountEventProcess;xxxProcess;
            bindings:
                userEventProcess-in-0:
                    destination: xxx.user
                userEventProcess-out-0:
                    destination: xxx.user_event
                accountEventProcess-in-0:
                    destination: xxx.user
                accountEventProcess-in-1:
                    destination: xxx.account
                accountEventProcess-out-0:
                    destination: xxx.account_event
                xxxProcess-in-0:
                    destination: xxx.user_event
                xxxProcess-in-1:
                    destination: xxx.account_event
                xxxProcess-out-0:
                    destination: xxx.final_result
```

But get the issues that: `The bean 'xxx.user_event' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is disabled.`

I have read some code from spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, found that in `KafkaStreamsBindableProxyFactory`, the method bindInput will register destination name as one bean, so this means we can not reuse the same topic for another processor?
Below is the code from `KafkaStreamsBindableProxyFactory.bindInput`

```
    private void bindInput(ResolvableType arg0, String inputName) {
    if (arg0.getRawClass() != null) {
        KafkaStreamsBindableProxyFactory.this.inputHolders.put(inputName,
                new BoundTargetHolder(getBindingTargetFactory(arg0.getRawClass())
                        .createInput(inputName), true));
    }

    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;

    RootBeanDefinition rootBeanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition();
    rootBeanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(() -> inputHolders.get(inputName).getBoundTarget());
    registry.registerBeanDefinition(inputName, rootBeanDefinition);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using this property in **application.properties**
`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`?

Comment: I am not sure this solution can work or not, the official document does not describe this

Comment: I would try first, here is [reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-definition-override-exception#4-beans-coming-from-3rd-party-libraries).